# Enviar uma List<T> com vários itens para o controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, controller

Bom, estou enfrentando o seguinte problema em um projeto em que estou trabalho: como passar uma lista (List) com aprox. 500~1000 linhas da View para o Controller?

Na realidade, essa minha lista possui um campo chamado "Selected (bool)" do qual o usuário seleciona apenas as linhas que ele deseja gerar uma ação, o que dá em torno de 50, 100, ou até às vezes todas elas.

Estou construindo isso em uma 'table' e  realizando um "for" para popular a mesma. O tempo de resposta para construir a View está excelente, mas para mandar a lista para meu controlador e começar a validar as linhas selecionadas e, posteriormente, gravar no banco de dados, está absurdamente lento/travado. Meu controlador está recebendo a List como parâmetro e realizando as ações após o recebimento.

Meu Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(List<MyClass> list) {
    foreach (var item in list) {
        if (item.Checked) {
            // realiza ações
        }
    }
}
```

Minha View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @* Aqui fica todo o cabeçalho (th) e componentes HTML *@

    @for (int r = 0; r < Model.Count(); r++)
    {
        <tr class="tr-clickable">
            @Html.HiddenFor(i => i[r].ID_Usuario)
            <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(i => i[r].Checked)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(i => i[r].Matricula)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(i => i[r].Nome)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(i => i[r].Value)</td>
        </tr>
    }

    @* Aqui ficam os componentes HTML restantes *@

    <div class="control-group margin-top-20 pull-right">
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Gerar" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Há alguma maneira mais inteligente de se fazer essa "passagem"?

Pensei em fazer via ajax-jQuery, passando linha-a-linha e gravando uma-a-uma. Funciona. Porém, o usuário tem que ter o poder de dar o submit somente quando ele tiver certeza das linhas selecionadas...

Comment: Poste como está seu controller.

Comment: @Randrade editado!

Comment: Creio que o *Model Binder* não foi feito para trabalhar com tantos registros numa só requisição. Acho que seria melhor você simplificar a modelagem, fazendo a *Action* receber um dicionário.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Dicionário? Acho que não entendi muito bem... Um objeto do tipo "Dictionary"? ^~

Comment: @AntônioFilho Isso mesmo. Pode por favor colocar sua *View* na pergunta?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Editado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi este problema usando jQuery-Ajax:

```
   $('input[type="button"][data-submit]').click(function () {

        if (confirm('Você confirma?')) {

            var array = [];

            $('#table > tbody > tr').each(function () {
                var $tr = $(this);
                // aqui é só colocar algo que filtre apenas as tr's com um checkbox igual a true (':checked')
                var usid = $tr.find('[data-usid]').val();
                var irvlr = $tr.find('[data-irvlr]').val();
                array.push({
                    User: usid,
                    Value: irvlr
                });
            });

            if (array.length > 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ 'list': array }),
                    success: function (result) {
                        window.location.href = result.url;
                    },
                    error: function (ex) {
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                alert('No items selected.');
            }

        }

    });
```

Obrigado a todos!

Answer (score 4):

Se você quer passar a lista para a `View` para alterar somente no `submit`, acho que a melhor opção seria você fazer o `foreach()` somente com os itens selecionados, desta forma:

```
public ActionResult Create(List<MyClass> list) {
    foreach (var item in list.Where(l => l.Selected)) {

            // realiza ações

    }
}
```

Desta forma irá percorrer a lista somente dos que estiverem selecionados.

Comment: @AntonioFilho faça um teste e me avise. Caso ainda esteja demorando, podemos ver uma forma de enviar somente os selecionados para o controller.

Comment: Sim, até ai tudo bem. O problema é que a lista nem chega no meu controller. Quando há mais ou menos uns 200 itens nesta lista e e eu do um submit no form, ele nem chega a carregar o controller, fica tipo travado...

Answer (score 2):

O mais interessante seria saber como está o seu `Controller` e `View`. Mas vou tentar te mostrar através de um exemplo prático:

Vamos imaginar que você precisa que o usuário selecione apenas os produtos que ele quer comprar e enviar para o servidor. Porém, você só precisa saber qual é o `Id` de cada produto selecionado para fazer a compra de fato.

A classe `Product`ficaria assim:

```
namespace AntonioFilho.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public decimal Price {get; set;}
    }
}
```

O `Controller` ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
namespace AntorioFilho.Controllers
{
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        // Camada fictícia apenas para ilustração ;)
        private IProductRepository _repository = new ProductRepository();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
             return View();
        }
        public ActionResult Buy()
        {
            IList<Product> products = _repository.GetAllProducts();
            return View(products);
        }

        [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Buy(List<Product> products)
        {
            bool ok = _repository.SelectProducts(products);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Já a sua `View` seria assim:

```
@model IList<Product>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Buy", "Product", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" id="checkall" /></th>
            <th>Product name</th>
        </tr>
    @for(int i = 0;i < Model.Length;i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Price, new { @disabled = "disabled", @id = String.Format("product{0}", i) })
                @Html.CheckboxFor(m => Model[i].Id, new { @class = "check", @idFake = String.Format("product{0}", i) })
            </td>
            <td>@Model[i].Name</td>
        </tr>
    }
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" value="comprar" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.check').click(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('idFake');
            if(this.checked)
                $('#' + id).removeAttr('disabled');
            else
                $('#' + id).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Espero ter ajudado \o/

Comment: @UliQueMessias obrigado pela ajuda. Então, basicamente é o que eu faço hoje, porém eu passo uma List<T>. O que acontece é que eu tenho que passar 2 atributos, o atributo ID e o atributo VALOR (pois o mesmo é um valor momentâneo, que pode ser alterado em um futuro).

Comment: @AntônioFilho, daí você pode adicionar `Javascript` e alterar o `Controller` para tratar esse caso. Fiz uma edição na resposta.

Comment: Dessa forma, você consegue enviar apenas o que você precisa.

Comment: @UliqueMessias Mas como que eu vou receber os campos ID e o campo Valor? O JS que você inseriu ele só mexe no componente em si..

Comment: @AntônioFilho, todos os `<input type="algumacoisa" />` do HTML que estiverem dentro de um `<form></form>` serão enviados para o servidor. No caso do `<input type="checkbox" />`, ele só será enviado se estiver marcado. Sendo assim, quando você o marcar, irá habilitar o outro controle "irmão" que está escondido (`<input type="hidden" />`) e quando o usuário clicar em **submit**, enviará apenas os `Product`s que estiverem marcados.

Comment: @AntônioFilho, se a minha ou outra resposta resolveu o seu problema, você poderia marcar como "resposta"?

Comment: @UliqueMessias é que na realidade eu ainda não tive uma resposta "plausível" ainda. A sua resposta, por exemplo, ela funciona. Porém se eu tiver uma tabela com 1000 linhas e selecionar 500, ainda assim irá demorar para fazer o HttpPost entende...

Comment: @AntônioFilho, compreendo. Mas dessa forma, você não vai encontrar uma resposta pausível por tão cedo, a não ser que esse "demorar muito" seja algo acima dos 3 segundos. Nesse caso, você teria que rever a estrutura da sua aplicação (ver se não tem algum `Handler` no seu `pipeline` fazendo operações desnecessárias a cada `requisição`) ou até mesmo a sua conexão com a internet (no caso de teste com um servidor externo) ou as configurações do seu computador (caso ele esteja muito lento).

Comment: Caso o problema seja no `pipeline`. Aconselho olhar no `Global.asax.cs` ou nos arquivos `Startup.cs`. Pode ser que algum script esteja sendo executado sem necessidade a cada requisição e isso leva a sua aplicação a demorar mais para responder.